# Pandas excel: write rows with NaN values in a separate DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, nan

I have df with 2 columns: Name, Number.
I need to write a row if NaN in cell to a new DataFrame.

```
path = 'Files/Directory.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path)
```

I've tried so many different things, spent 3 days and still can't get it.

Comment: would be great if you can give examples of your input and expected output tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["Alex", "Bob", "Jim", np.nan, np.nan],
        "Number": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, np.nan],
    }
)
df
```

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | 1.0 |
| Bob | 2.0 |
| Jim | NaN |
| NaN | 3.0 |
| NaN | NaN |

So it depends if you want to write rows with any NaN values to a new DataFrame or if you just want to write rows with all NaN values to the new DataFrame.

If any, the following should work:

```
df_nan = df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
df_nan
```

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Jim | NaN |
| NaN | 3.0 |
| NaN | NaN |

If all, this should work:

```
df_nan = df.loc[df.isnull().all(axis=1)]
df_nan
```

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN |

Comment: I appreciated it! I definitely worked. And it's something that I've tried before. I found out that it did not work for me, because there's something wrong in my code.
```path = '/Files/Directory-All.xlsx'```
```df = pd.read_excel(path)```

```def remove_special_char_from_numbers(number):
    number_ = str(number["Number"])
    return re.sub(r'[^0-9]+', '', number_)```
If I run:
```df["Number"] = df.apply(lambda x: remove_special_char_from_numbers(x), axis=1)```
before:
``df_nan = df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]``

it doesn't work.

Comment: when I do: ``df["Number"] = df.apply(lambda x: remove_special_char_from_numbers(x), axis=1)`` before ``df_nan = df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]`` - then I get: ``    Name      Number
0    NaN  7735633436
89   NaN            
94   NaN            
154  NaN            
194  NaN            
203  NaN            
209  NaN            
252  NaN            
261  NaN            
319  NaN            
365  NaN            
691  NaN            
714  NaN            
824  NaN            
869  NaN            
870  NaN            
871  NaN            
921  NaN            
954  NaN ``